# Having problem while copying sqlite database from assets to data folder

Tags: android

I don't understand why I'm not able to copy my db file (index.db) to the application directory "/data/data/com.cmc.sqlitedb/databases/") This is my DataBaseHelper class

```
package com.cmc.sqlitedb;

import java.io.*;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipInputStream;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;




public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    //The Android's default system path of your application database.
    private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.cmc.sqlitedb/databases/";

    private static String DB_NAME = "index.db";

    private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase; 

    //private final Context myContext;
    private final Context Ctxt;

    /**
     * Constructor
     * Takes and keeps a reference of the passed context in order to access to the application assets and resources.
     * @param context
     */
    public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {

        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
        this.Ctxt = context;
    }   

  /**
     * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own database.
     * */
    public void createDataBase() throws IOException
    {
         File Path = Ctxt.getDir("Data", 0);
         File DBFile = new File(Path, "Index.db"); 


        Log.v("4","four");
        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

        if(dbExist)
        {
            Log.v("5","five");
            //do nothing - database already exist
        }
        else
        {
            Log.v("6","six");
            //By calling this method and empty database will be created into the default system path
               //of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that database with our database.

            this.getReadableDatabase();

            try 
            {
                Log.v("7","seven");
               //copyDataBase(Ctxt, DBFile);
               copyDataBase();
                Log.v("copyDataBase","after copyDataBase");
            } 
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                throw new Error("Error copying database");
            }
        }
    }


    /**
     * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each time you open the application.
     * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
     */

    private boolean checkDataBase(){

        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

        try{
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

        }catch(SQLiteException e){

            //database does't exist yet.

        }

        if(checkDB != null){

            checkDB.close();

        }

        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }

    /**
     * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the
     * system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
     * This is done by transfering bytestream.
     * */
    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{
        Log.v("8","eight");        

        //Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myInput = Ctxt.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(myInput);

//      InputStream myInput = myContext.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.freq_app);
        Log.v("9","nine");
        // Path to the just created empty db
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        Log.v("DB_PATH",DB_NAME);
        //Open the empty db as the output stream

          File f = new File( DB_PATH );
          if ( !f.exists() )
              f.mkdir();


        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        //.createNewFile(); 

        Log.v("OutputStream","OutputStream");

        //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[6624256];
        int length;
```

> here it throws error in while loop IOexception

```
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }           
        //Close the streams
        myInput.close();
        Log.v("COPY DATA BASE","end of copyDataBase");
    }


    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{

        //Open the database
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {

            if(myDataBase != null)
                myDataBase.close();

            super.close();

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    }
        // Add your public helper methods to access and get content from the database.
       // You could return cursors by doing "return myDataBase.query(....)" so it'd be easy
       // to you to create adapters for your views.
}

main class :
package com.cmc.sqlitedb;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.cmc.sqlitedb.DataBaseHelper;
import com.cmc.sqlitedb.R;

public class SqLiteTest extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    private TextView Colors;
    private Button click;
    private String result1=null;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        db = openOrCreateDatabase(
                "index.db"
                , SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY
                , null

    );
        Log.v("size of db", ""+db.getMaximumSize());
       DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);
            myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);
              try 
              {
                myDbHelper.createDataBase();
                Log.v("done", "Done");
              } 
              catch (IOException ioe) 
              {
              throw new Error("Unable to create database");
              } 


        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Colors=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.color);
        click=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Button);

        click.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {       
            public void onClick(View view) 
            {               
                try{
                                        //code to connect db  and get data frm db

                    result1=colorDetails(); 
                    Log.v("Result1",""+result1);



                }

                 catch(Exception e)
                {
                    System.out.println(e);
                }
               db.close();
            }

    });
 }

    public String colorDetails()
    {   

        Log.v("Reading", "reading");
        Cursor cur = db.rawQuery("select * from chip LIMIT 20",null);
        Log.v("Reading ok", "reading ok");
        Log.v("",""+cur.getString(9));          

            return result1; 

}
}
```

Comment: user606436 - you've sent a mass of code, most of which doesn't relate at all to your issue - it would probably be much easier for people to read and answer if you gave more info about the *exact problem*, and limited the post to relevant code. At the moment, most people will see "tl;dr;"

Comment: are you copying en encrypted db?

Answer (score 1):

```
private void copyDataBase(Context myContext) throws IOException {
    File fileTest = myContext.getFileStreamPath(DB_NAME);
    boolean exists = fileTest.exists();
    if (!exists) {
        // Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream databaseOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
        InputStream databaseInputStream;

        databaseInputStream = myContext.getAssets().open(DBpart1);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = databaseInputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            databaseOutputStream.write(buffer);
        }
        databaseInputStream.close();

        databaseInputStream = myContext.getAssets().open(DBpart2);
        while ((length = databaseInputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            databaseOutputStream.write(buffer);
        }

        // Close the streams
        databaseInputStream.close();
        databaseOutputStream.flush();
        databaseOutputStream.close();
    }
}
```